# Wordpress, It doesn't show limit posts in home page

Tags: wordpress

I created a wordpress theme, in home page, as i see in another templates for fetch limit numbers of posts in home page. a code like belowe has been developed:

```
<?php
$featuredPosts->query('showposts=40');
while ($featuredPosts->have_posts()  ) : $featuredPosts->the_post(); ?>

<!-- blah blah -->

<?php endwhile;?>
```

But it shows 35 posts in, how can i fix it? Does it depend on server speed?

Comment: `showposts` is deprecated use `posts_per_page` http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters

Comment: Thanks, <?php query_posts( 'posts_per_page=40' ); ?>
worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$featuredPosts->query('posts_per_page=40');
```

showposts (int) - number of post to show per page. Deprecated as of WP Version 2.1 in favor of 'posts_per_page'.

Answer (score 0):

**Point 1**: first check do you have 40 or more post

try that code

```
 <?php query_posts("showposts=40"); ?>
```

or

```
<?php query_posts( 'posts_per_page=40' ); ?>
```

and check also in wp_admin panel Setting->Reading Sestting->**Blog pages show at most**

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there are more than 35 posts in the category you are querying? I think the **query** method you are using should be **query_posts**. A more standard conform loop would be:

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=40');  
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();  
?>
```